# React acusing a memory leak in my application

Tags: reactjs

I searched a lot about this error, but React continues to report it:

"react_devtools_backend.js:2430 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function."

My code is below:

```
const [books, setBooks] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
let isMounted = false

BookAPI.getAll().then(books => {
  if (!isMounted) setBooks(books)
})

return () => {
  isMounted = true
 }
}, [])
```

For what I searched, I am doing the clean up part right, but I don't understand why the error persists.

Edit:

Tried this too, and nothing changed:

```
  let [books, setBooks] = useState([])
  let isRendered = useRef(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    BookAPI.getAll().then(books => {
      if (!isRendered.current) setBooks(books)
      return null
    })

    return () => {
      isRendered.current = true
    }
  }, [])
```

Comment: `!isMounted` is always true in this scenario, it might be better to use `useRef` to store the value.

Comment: Post more of your code. your `useEffect` should work fine under a basic scenario. How do we reproduce your error without seeing the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumble in this same issue, my solution was to use useLayoutEffect instead of useEffect.